# Trying to install e(fx)clipse, but nothing is working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler, efxclipse

NB I am using Eclipse Kepler and version 4.3.2.M20140221-1700 according to the config file.

For a grand majority of the software I try to install through eclipse, conflictions arise which prevent me from downloading it altogether.

Trying the Eclipse marketplace, I've attempted to download e(fx)clipse there - but the same problems occur.

Looking around, some say I need xtext which I did try and download just for the sake of trying. However, even with this proposed solution I'm stuck.

These are the details after the installation attempt:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

> Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.1.0.201508240705
>   (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.201508240705)
>   Missing requirement: Guice integration for FXML 2.1.0.201508240602
>   (org.eclipse.fx.core.guice 2.1.0.201508240602) requires 'package
>   org.osgi.framework 1.8.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic 2.1.0.201508240705 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.201508240705)
>       To: org.eclipse.fx.core.guice [2.1.0.201508240602]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.1.0.201508240705 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.201508240705)
>       To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group [2.1.0.201508240705]

I'm considering redownloading a newer version of Eclipse because even kepler doesn't let me update without having some kind of issues.

Comment: Unless you have serious reasons to not upgrade (like a lot of stuff configured; that might break when going to eclipse mars) ... just update. Fixing problems on "outdated" eclipses is simply spoken a waste of time.

Comment: When I click check for updates, it tells me that "sites could not be found" even when I deselect the sites listed in the details. It also tells me no updates have been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e(fx)clipse generally requires to be installed on the current version of Eclipse and won't install on older versions.

Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2) is the current version. The [e(fx)clipse site](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html) has links to a download which contains an Eclipse build with e(fx)clipse already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Never use latest version of eclipse because most of the latest version cannot download e(fx)clipse,same problem occur to me too. suppose eclipse 2020 is the latest version than use eclipse 2018-19.Thank you